# How to get this jQuery Counter working?

Tags: jquery

OK so I needed an odometer style **jQuery counter** and found [this neat one] http://nleach.com/post/16045448547/odometer-style-counter-using-jquery .

I checked on Fiddle but cant get all the elements to work. Below is where I have reached so far.

```
            <html>
            <head>


              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <style>
            .counter {
                display:block;
                float:left;
                font-size:2em;
                line-height:1.2em;
                -webkit-box-reflect: below -15px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(60%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.3)));
            }

            .counter span.digit {
                background:#161616;
                background: #3F3F3F; /* Old browsers */
                background: linear-gradient(bottom, #0A0A0A 0%, #2B2B2B 50%, #3F3F3F 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0A0A0A 0%, #2B2B2B 50%, #3F3F3F 100%);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0A0A0A 0%, #2B2B2B 50%, #3F3F3F 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0A0A0A 0%, #2B2B2B 50%, #3F3F3F 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #0A0A0A 0%, #2B2B2B 50%, #3F3F3F 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #0A0A0A), color-stop(0.5, #2B2B2B), color-stop(1, #3F3F3F));
                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FF0A0A0A', endColorstr='#FF3F3F3F'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FF0A0A0A', endColorstr='#FF3F3F3F')"; /* IE8 */
                zoom:1;    -webkit-border-radius:0.1em;
                -moz-border-radius:0.1em;
                border-radius:0.1em;
                background-clip:border;
                color:#FFF;
                display:block;
                float:left;
                height:44px;
                margin:0 1px;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:0;
                position:relative;
                text-align:center;
                width:30px;
            }

            .counter span.digit span {
                line-height:44px;
                position:relative;
                top:0;
            }

            .counter span.digit hr {
                border-color: transparent;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px   rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                height: 3px;
                margin: -2px 0 0 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .counter span.separator {
                display:block;
                float:left;
                font-family:Georgia, serif;
                font-size:0.5em;
                position:relative;
                top:0.5em;
            }

            .counter span.separator hr {
                display:none;
            }
            </style>

            </head>
            <body onLoad:"initCounter()">
            <script language="Javscript">
            ;(function($){
                /*
                    Function: initCounter

                    Initializes the scrolling counter using the value currently displayed in the element.

                    Parameters:

                        $this - the counter container
                        e - jQuery Event object

                    See Also:

                        <animateDigit>
                */
                function initCounter($this, e){
                    $this.find('.digit').each(function(){
                        var $display = $(this);
                        var $digit = $display.find('span');

                        $digit.html([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0].reverse().join('<br/>'))
                        $digit.css({
                            top: '-' + (parseInt($display.height()) * (10 - parseInt($digit.attr('title')))) + 'px'
                        });
                    });

                    animateDigit($this.find('.digit:last'), e);
                }

                /*
                    Function: animateDigit

                    Moves the digit indicated by $this one step. If the end of the counter has been reach, the subsequent digit(s) will also be rotated

                    Parameters:

                        $this - digit to be rotated
                        e - jQuery Event object
                */
                function animateDigit($this, e){
                    var $counter = $this.closest('.counter');
                    var $display = $this;
                    var $digit = $display.find('span');

                    // If we've reached the end of the counter, tick the previous digit
                    if(parseInt($digit.css('top')) == -1 * parseInt($display.height())){
                        animateDigit($display.prevAll('.digit:first'), e);
                    }

                    $digit.animate({
                        top: '+=' + $display.height() + 'px'
                    }, 500, function(){
                        // Repeat the animation on a semi-random interval
                        if($display.index('.counter .digit') == $counter.find('.digit').length - 1){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                animateDigit($display, e);
                            }, Math.max(550, Math.random() * 10000));
                        }

                        // If we've reached the end of the counter, loop back to the top
                        if(parseInt($digit.css('top')) > -1 * parseInt($display.height())){
                            $digit.css({
                                top: '-' + (parseInt($display.height()) * 10) + 'px'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                $(function(){
                    initCounter($('.counter'), $.Event('load'));
                });
            })(jQuery);

            </script>

            <span class="counter">
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="3">3</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="separator">
                    <span title=",">,</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="2">2</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="4">4</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="4">4</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="separator">
                    <span title=",">,</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="4">4</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="1">1</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
                <span class="digit">
                    <span title="8">8</span>
                    <hr />
                </span>
            </span>
            </body>
            </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Seems to be working like the link you provided when I used jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VSSet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you don't need the onload function in the body.

```
<body onLoad:"initCounter()">
```

Just

```
<body>
```

jQuery will handle the load event here:

```
$(function(){
  initCounter($('.counter'), $.Event('load'));
});
```

Your other problem is just a typo. You have:

```
<script language="Javscript">
```

Instead of

```
<script language="javascript">
```

The browser doesn't know what "Javscript" (missing an A) is. :)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Guess should not be trying out this stuff at 2:00 AM through galzed eyes. Thanks again.